# nqsError 14046 in OBIEE. No Physical Join exits between two tables

Tags: oracle, join, obiee

While consistency check doesn't show any errors, OBIEE says the following

```
no physical join relationships exist between any of the following tables: left = [ [[file: server/Query/Optimizer/Navigator/Src/SQONPathJoinConstructor.cpp; line: 720

    Table A T44064] and right = [Table B T93025].
```

These two tables are not related and there is no need for any joins between them. I looked at the logs, they don't give any key info. They only have a record of presentation level query. However, in OBIS log, where the error is written I have one more line.

What could be a reason?

Edit. These two unrelated tables are dimension tables if it has any importance

Comment: Are you trying to use only dimensions in your report? Have you defined an implicit fact column?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? And what are those tables in your model? Dimensions? Facts? Snowflake? Extension?

Comment: I just added simple table  A to rpd, joined it withits parent table C  with id, consistency check said everything is ok, but when I tried to create an analysis then I got the above error that table A has no join with table B. Neither table A nor table C has anything to do with table B and there are no joins with table B for these tables. Table A and Table B are dimension tables, parent Table B is connected to fact table F1.

Comment: OBI works (logically) with stars - so dimensions and facts. What is your table supposed to be?

Comment: I have a dimension table Clients,  I added one dimension table mobile_clients and joined it with table Clients by client_id. Table Clients is connected to Fact table Client_Stats. But in Obiie analysis I am getting that error that table mobile_clients and third non-related table Company_Posts are not joined. Company_Posts table is not related to Clients or mobile_clients. I dont understand this, why it asks for join between these table.

Comment: You're not being specific about physical versus logical model so based on such imprecise information i can't help you much.

Comment: What kind of information do you need? Everything is happening in logical model, neither in logical nor in physical layer there is a join between those tables. Both tables are dimension tables.The problem itself is described above. I'll provide every necessary information in case you need it.